# Stacked Mixed Horizontal Bar Chart in Charts.Js Axes Positioning

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a mixed stacked horizontal bar chart and line chart in Charts.js 3.2.0.

Expected behaviour: one axis at the bottom for the stacked bars including axes title and one axis at the top for the line chart.

Actual behaviour: all axes on the bottom with an additional extra axis displayed that doesn't seem to correspond with any dataset. No axes titles displayed.

Notes: the code has zero values for a few bars, these can be non-zero depending on data that is generated.

My code:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

    data: {
      labels: ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 6", ],
      datasets: [{
          type: "line",
          label: "Earnings",
          xAxisID: "A1",
          data: [10000, 20000, 30000, 5000]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 1",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(255,59,59, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(255,59,59, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 2",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(241,85,54, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(241,85,54, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 3",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(235,106,55, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(235,106,55, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 4",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(227,131,53, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(227,131,53, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 32.012777777778, 0, 0, 29.378611111111, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 5",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(221,171,54, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(221,171,54, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 6",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(218,199,52, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(218,199,52, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 44.195555555556, 0, 0, 38.79, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 7",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(192,224,66, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(192,224,66, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 14.921666666667, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 8",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(124,236,93, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(124,236,93, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [40.216666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },



      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      indexAxis: "y",
      scales: {
        x: [

          {
            display: true,
            position: "top",
            type: "linear",
            title: {
              text: "cost",
              display: true,
            },
            beginAtZero: true,
            id: "A1",


          },
          {
            id: "B1",
            position: "bottom",
            title: {
              text: "hours",
              display: false,
            },
            beginAtZero: true

          }
        ],

        y: {
          display: true,
          stacked: true,
          //beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkv3L8t0/)

[Screenshot of current behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLRyt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x and y axis are no arrays anymore in v3, all scales are an object and you define the place with the `position` argument, also you dont specify the id in the object but the object key is the id

Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

    data: {
      labels: ["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 6", ],
      datasets: [{
          type: "line",
          label: "Earnings",
          xAxisID: "A1",
          data: [10000, 20000, 30000, 5000]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 1",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(255,59,59, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(255,59,59, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 2",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(241,85,54, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(241,85,54, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 3",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(235,106,55, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(235,106,55, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 4",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(227,131,53, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(227,131,53, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 32.012777777778, 0, 0, 29.378611111111, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 5",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(221,171,54, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(221,171,54, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 6",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(218,199,52, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(218,199,52, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 44.195555555556, 0, 0, 38.79, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 7",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(192,224,66, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(192,224,66, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 14.921666666667, 0, 0, ]
        },

        {
          label: "CAT 8",
          xAxisID: "B1",
          type: "bar",
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(124,236,93, 0.2)"],
          borderColor: ["rgba(124,236,93, 1)"],
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: [40.216666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
        },



      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      indexAxis: "y",
      scales: {
        A1:

        {
          display: true,
          position: "top",
          type: "linear",
          title: {
            text: "cost",
            display: true,
          },
          beginAtZero: true,
          id: "A1",


        },
        B1: {
          id: "B1",
          position: "bottom",
          title: {
            text: "hours",
            display: false,
          },
          beginAtZero: true

        },

        y: {
          display: true,
          stacked: true,
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/7agx5hkr/1/

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and looks a lot clearner to implement. I've only recently started to migrate towards v3 but am enjoying the improvements